# KerasClassifier cannot be used as estimator in VotingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror

I am using scikit-learn and Keras for Machine Learning in python. I started to use the KerasClassifier wrapper for wrapping a sequential model of Keras to make it compatible with scikit-learn classifier related functions and API. Most of the functionality is easy to use (I could use the methods fit, predict, predict_proba and calculate the accuracy )
but when I tried to use KerasClassifier object as one of the estimators in  scikit-learn's voting classifier, I got errors.

How to resolve this?

```
eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators = [('k1',keras_clf1),('k2',keras_cl2)], voting='soft',weights= [1,1])
```

> TypeError: Cannot clone object '' (type ): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.

Comment: What is `keras_clf1` and `keras_cl2`? How have you defined it? Post the complete duplicateable code.